# Monitoring Bottle API in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, bottle

I'm running a Bottle API in an AWS server. From time to time the app goes down. What are effective ways to monitor if the API is running?
And in case it goes down, how can I turn it on again without the need to go to the server command line?

Answer (score -1):

if you run a docker container of the Bottle API you can tell docker to restart the API whenever it goes down using the `restart: always` setting.
E.G (assuming you built the docker container)

In the docker-compose.yml file

```
BottleAPI:
    #settings and what to run here
    restart: always
```

Comment: I don't use docker

Comment: The alternative would be to have a python script that checks `netstat` for your service and if it's not there boot it up again.